# string vector to 2d array of chars for shell program

Tags: c++, shell

I'm writing a shell program and I know that execvp needs to take in execvp(args[start], args). Initially I read in the command and parse it into a string, storing the "|" to know where the multiple commands are split. Now I'm trying to convert the vector to a 2d array of chars. Don't know if this is right, but I was thinking that each row would be a char* with the a set of commands and arguments. That way I could loop through this when setting up the piping. Here's the code I have so far:

```
char** vectorToChar(char** arr, vector<string> cmdsAndArgs)
{
    char* cmd;
    char** args;

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (vector<string>::iterator it = cmdsAndArgs.begin(); it < cmdsAndArgs.end(); it++) {
        string s = *it;
        if (s == "|") {
            cmd[j] = 0;
            args[i] = cmd;
            i++;
            j = 0;
        } else {
            cmd[j] = *(char*)s.c_str();
            j++;
        }
    }
    cmd[j] = 0;
    args[i] = cmd;
    args[++i] = 0;

    cout << endl << args[0][0] << endl;

    return args;
}
```

Getting Bus error: 10

Answer (score 2):

```
char* cmd;
```

You only declared a pointer, but you didn't allocated any space for it.

Comment: If I allocate space with char* cmd[100]; then instead I get error: assigning to 'char *' from incompatible type 'char *[100]'

Comment: It should be `char cmd[100];`

Comment: That partially works. When I try to use ls command, I cout args[0][0] = l. But want I wand is args[0][0] = ls.

Comment: `args[0][0]` is only single character. You may `cout << args[0]` to see if your logic is correct.